# Как заполнить массив символами без ввода с клавиатуры?

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

Как заполнить массив символами без ввода с клавиатуры?

```
char* mass = new char[10];
mass = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '/', 'f', 'a', 'g', 'd']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, такк:

```
char* mass = new char[10] {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '/', 'f', 'a', 'g', 'd'};
```

Можно и так:

```
char* mass = new char[11] {"12345/fagd"};
```

Только нужно на один элемент больше - для завершающего нулевого символа...

Можно и скопировать после выделения памяти - типа

```
char* mass = new char[10];
strncpy(mass,"12345/fagd",10);
```